# getting error -> does not support the API version '2022-05-01' while making query for AZURE-ARM using CURL

Tags: azure, curl, azure-resource-manager, azure-cli, api-versioning

I am trying to get the AML token using CLI.
I am able to get the token using the command -> **token=$(az account get-access-token --subscription {subscri ID} --resource-type arm --query accessToken --output tsv)**

but when I use this token to get the AMLToken I get below error, however it is working fine if I make this query using postman :
**curl -d POST --header "Authorization: Bearer $token" "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subcri id}/resourceGroups/{res_grup}/providers/Microsoft.MachineLearningServices/workspaces/{workspace}/onlineEndpoints/{endpoint}/token?api-version=2022-05-01"**

the error which I get is below :

{
"error": {
"code": "UnsupportedApiVersion",
"message": "The HTTP resource that matches the request URI 'https://cert-eastus2.experiments.azureml.net/mferp/managementfrontend/subscriptions/{sub_id}/resourceGroups/{r_group}/providers/Microsoft.MachineLearningServices/workspaces/{workspace}/onlineEndpoints/{endpoint}/token' does not support the API version '2022-05-01'.",
"innerError": null
}
}

any helps or pointers please, why I am getting this error? Not able to find any documentation for it.

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the below results***

I ran the **same commands** as you and got the **same error** as below:

```bash
token=$(az account get-access-token --subscription subscriptionID --resource-type arm --query accessToken --output tsv)
url="https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/subscriptionID/resourceGroups/rgname/providers/Microsoft.MachineLearningServices/workspaces/workspace_name/onlineEndpoints/endpoint_name/token?api-version=2022-05-01"
curl -d POST --header "Authorization: Bearer $token" $url
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I did the same via ***Postman***, I got the **`AML token`** successfully like below:

[image]

**Alternatively**, make use of below **Azure CLI** command to get **`AML token`** like below:

```bash
az ml online-endpoint get-credentials --name <endpoint_name> --resource-group <rg_name> --workspace-name <workspace_name>
```

I ran the same command and got **`AML token`** successfully like below:

[image]

When I decoded the token in [**jwt.ms**](https://jwt.ms/), I got the **claims** same as token from **Postman** like below:

[image]